# Remove a known subset of nodes from JSON, in SQLAzure

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Once upon a time, there was one row of data (massively simplified, the actual json data is 10KB+) thus:

```
ID, json
1, '{
      "a1.arr": [1,2,3],
      "a1.boo": true,
      "a1.str": "hello",
      "a1.num": 123
    }'
```

A process was supposed to write another record with predominantly different data:

```
ID, json
2, '{
      "a1.arr": [1,2,3], //from ID 1
      "a2.arr": [4,5,6], //new (and so are all below)
      "a2.boo": false,
      "a2.str": "goodbye",
      "a2.num": 456
    }'
```

But due to some external error, the original set of json from ID 1 ended up also being represented in ID 2, so now the table looks like this:

```
ID, json
1, '{
      "a1.arr": [1,2,3],
      "a1.boo": true,
      "a1.str": "hello",
      "a1.num": 123
    }'
2, '{
      "a1.arr": [1,2,3],
      "a1.boo": true,    //extraneous
      "a1.str": "hello", //extraneous
      "a1.num": 123,     //extraneous
      "a2.arr": [4,5,6],
      "a2.boo": false,
      "a2.str": "goodbye",
      "a2.num": 456
    }'
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to remove the extraneous lines from the ID 2 record.

I believe that the entire JSON string from ID 1 is represented in ID 2 as a contiguous block, so string replacement *could* work but there's a chance that some reordering has taken place. Gets a bit messy with the element that is supposed to remain, though

There's also a chance that some of the a1.* nodes' values have been changed slightly, (I didn't do a diff) but I'm happy to use just the node names, not their values, in assessing whether an node should be removed. One of the nodes (`a1.arr`) should be kept in ID 2. The resultset should hence look like:

```
ID, json
1, '{
      "a1.arr": [1,2,3],
      "a1.boo": true,
      "a1.str": "hello",
      "a1.num": 123
    }'
2, '{
      "a1.arr": [1,2,3],
      "a2.arr": [4,5,6],
      "a2.boo": false,
      "a2.str": "goodbye",
      "a2.num": 456
    }'
```

I've started playing about with https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168303/can-sql-server-2016-extract-node-names-from-json to get the list of node names from ID 1 that I want to remove from ID 2, just not sure how I then strip them out of ID 2's JSON - presumably a deserialize, reduce and reserialize sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this approach:

1. get the keys you want to replace with an `openjson` on row with `id=1` value
2. use `cross apply` to filter keys in rows with `id>1`
3. rebuild the json string without unwanted keys using `STRING_AGG` and `group by`

This code should work:

```
declare @tmp table ([id] int, jsonValue nvarchar(max))
declare @source_json nvarchar(max)

insert into @tmp values
 (1, '{"a1.arr":[1,2,3],"a1.boo":true,"a1.str":"hello","a1.num":123}')
,(2, '{"a1.arr":[1,2,3],"a1.boo":true,"a1.str":"hello","a1.num":123,"a2.arr":[4,5,6],"a2.boo":false,"a2.str":"goodbye","a2.num":456}')
,(3, '{"a1.arr":[1,2,3],"a1.boo":true,"a1.str":"hello","a1.num":123,"a3.arr":[4,5,6],"a3.boo":false,"a3.str":"goodbye","a3.num":456}')

--get json string from id=1
select @source_json = jsonValue from @tmp where [id] = 1

--rebuild json string for id > 1 removing keys from id = 1
select t.[id],   
       '{' + STRING_AGG( '"' + g.[key] + '":"' + STRING_ESCAPE(g.[value], 'json')  + '"', ',') + '}' as [json]
from @tmp t cross apply openjson(jsonValue) g
where t.id > 1
    and g.[key] not in (select [key] from openjson(@source_json) where [key] <> 'a1.arr')
group by t.id
```

Result:

[image]